# Count adjacent lines with different beginnings

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have text files that are transcriptions of conversations, for example:

```
Speaker1: Hello. 
Speaker2: Hi. 
Speaker2: How are you? 
Speaker1: Well thanks.
```

I would like to count how many times the speaker *changes* from line to line. So for this example, it would be 2 (line 1 to 2, and line 3 to 4, but not line 2 to 3).

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk -F':' '(NR>1) && ($1!=prev){c++} {prev=$1} END{print c+0}' file
2
```

Answer (score 1):

A cumulative, "piped" approach would be like this:

- cut everything after the speaker (first colon): `cut -f1 -d:`
- eliminate repetitions: `uniq`
- count lines: `wc -l`

So, `cut -f1 -d: < yourfile | uniq | wc -l` should yield the desired result.

## update

As @EdMorton observed, the result are off by one (the number of *changes* are one less the number of lines, and the above counts the number of lines). If you can manage it, just take that into account. Otherwise, you can add a stage to skip the first line after the `uniq`: `uniq | tail -n +2`.

Comment: @EdMorton good catch. *Changes* are wanted, and obviously the number of changes is one less the number of lines. Thanks, updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Python module `itertools` has a method `groupby` which groups data on keys whenever the key changes value. We make the first field delimited on colon as our key and group around it.

```
python3 -c 'import sys, itertools as it
k,g = -1,lambda x: x.split(":")[0]
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  for t in it.groupby(f,g): k += 1
print(k)
' file
2
```

---

`GNU sed` can do it by looking at two lines at a time. When the first fields delimited in colon differ, we append a newline to the hold. At eof, print the hold after stripping one newline to account for the newline being implicitly added by sed while printing.

```
sed -En '
  $!N
  /^([^:]+:).*\n\1/!{x;s/$/\n/;x;}
  $!D
  g;s/.//p
' file|wc -l
```

---

Perl in slurp mode (0777) , using the power of regexes, remove the consecutive repeating lines with same first fields delimited on colon. Then count the number of newlines.

```
perl -pl -0777 -e '
  s/^(([^:]+:).*\n)(?:\2.*\n)+/$1/mg;
  $_ = tr/\n// -1;
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F"[a-z]|:" '! count[$7]++ {cnt++} END {print cnt + 0}' input_file
2
```

Count the unique value after the word `Speaker` but before `:`

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -e '(-1 + slurp.split(/<[:\v]>/)[0,2,4...*]>>.match(/\d+$/).[0..(*-2)]>>.Int.squish.elems).say;'
```

OR

```
raku -e '(-1 + slurp.comb(/ ^^ \w+ <(\d+)> \: \s /).squish.elems).say;'
```

Briefly (second solution, above), `slurp` the file, `comb` select out elements that match (in order) `^^` start-of-line, `\w+` alnum(s), `\:` colon and `\s` whitespace, using the `<(…)>` operator drop everything but the digits, `squish` adjacent identical digits leaving only one, get number of `elems` elements, then `-1` (subtract one) and `say` the answer.

Sample Input (OP's, duplicated 2X):

```
Speaker1: Hello. 
Speaker2: Hi. 
Speaker2: How are you? 
Speaker1: Well thanks..
Speaker1: Hello. 
Speaker2: Hi. 
Speaker2: How are you? 
Speaker1: Well thanks..
Speaker1: Hello. 
Speaker2: Hi. 
Speaker2: How are you? 
Speaker1: Well thanks..
```

Sample Output (`perl6 -e 'slurp.comb(/ ^^ \w+ <(\d+)> \: \s /).say;'`)

```
(1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1)
```

Sample Output (`perl6 -e 'slurp.comb(/ ^^ \w+ <(\d+)> \: \s /).squish.say;'`)

```
(1 2 1 2 1 2 1)
```

Sample Output (final, second code line from top):

```
6
```

https://raku.org